# Get only those files in a directory whose name does not start with a certain string

Tags: vb.net, linq, directoryinfo

I currently have this code:

```
    Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Scratch")

    For Each FInfo As IO.FileInfo In FolderInfo.GetFiles("*.xlsx")

        MessageBox.Show(FInfo.ToString())
    Next FInfo
```

Obviously this will get all the files that match the pattern "*.xlsx" - but I am NOT interested in any files that start with "old" - so of course within the For Next, I could do something like if If Not FInfo.Name.StartsWith("old") Then ... and do what I need to do, but I was wondering if there is any way to tell the GetFiles to only get files that "don't start with "old" and end in *.xlsx" ?

I've seen examples in C# that I believe use LINQ - so after the GetFiles there is stuff like ".Where(f => !(f.FullName.StartsWith("old")))" but not sure what ( if there is one ) the equivilant would be for VB.NET ?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: `.Where(Function(w) w.FullName.StartsWith("old") = False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a bit more verbose, but Where works as well in VB

```
For Each FInfo As IO.FileInfo In FolderInfo.GetFiles("*.xlsx").
    Where(Function(x) Not x.Name.StartsWith("old"))

    MessageBox.Show(FInfo.ToString())
Next FInfo
```

I would also add a `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` to remove also files that starts with "Old" or "OLD" and so on

```
For Each FInfo As IO.FileInfo In FolderInfo.GetFiles("*.xlsx").
    Where(Function(x) Not x.Name.StartsWith("old", StringComparisong.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

    MessageBox.Show(FInfo.ToString())
Next FInfo
```

By the way, you should use the property `Name` instead of `FullName`. FullName returns also the path to the file and, obviously, this path doesn't start with "old".

Comment: Cheers guys ! I've marked Steve's suggestion as the answer, as I was hoping to use the GetFiles - but both would have don the trick.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no way to change the GetFiles method of the DirectoryInfo class. You could create an extension method but it is only a way to hide the workings of code like the one above. Inside the extension method you have the same code

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim folder As String = "C:\Scratch"
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) _
     .Where(Function(f) Not Path.GetFileName(f).ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("old"))     

  For Each file As string In files
        MessageBox.Show(file)
  Next file
```